# Android - How to stop a phone call from destroying a TCP connection running in a service

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, timeout

I have a TCP client running in an asynchronomous task, started from a service. Everything appears to work normally but once I receive a call to my device, I get this error:

`java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)                                                                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)                                                                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)                                                                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)                                                                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)                                                                      at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)                                                                      at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)                                                                      at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)`

I think this has something to do with memory management, but my app really depends on this service and the TCP client must not lose the connection that easily. It was supposed to report incoming calls via a broadcast receiver. The service is started as `STICKY`. Log files indicate that calls are being logged. What could be a source of this problem? Every help appreciated.

Comment: Were you on WiFi or mobile data at the time? 

This is something that I'd expect as the phone may connect to a new mast on 3g instead of 4g.

Comment: @apmartin1991 it might be possible, but the behavior is different depending on the device. On the emulator, it always does that, but on the phone, when I call somebody, it stays connected for a few seconds (up to a minute), and then "dies". When the call is received, it dies instantly. Now, the phone is quite old, so I guess memory management is the issue here. Looks like only 0.89 MB of memory is free. Is there any way I could fix this, for older phones? (process priority or something).

Comment: @apmartin1991 you were right!! After a few tests, I've found that, if I have both packet data and WiFi on, the connection gets interrupted when the device receives a phone call, even when the WiFi is connected to a hot-spot. The device somehow switches the interfaces for a short period of time which causes the network timeout. Now,  is there a way to prevent this?